# Supremum and infimum of the set ${(n+2)/(n^2+1) }$

Tags: real-analysis

The question doesn't explicitly say whether it is on $\mathbb {N}$ or anything. But i'm assuming its on $\mathbb {R} $.

Since I couldn't arrange the equation i tried to separate it as $A=\{\ n /
 (n^2+1)\}$ and $ B= \{\ 2/( n^2+1 ) \}$ (Because $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A) + \sup(B)$, not sure if i can use this property like this). Since $(n-1)^2 > 0$, $n^2+1>2n$. Hence $1/2 \geq n/(n^2+1)$. Equality is only satisfied for $n=1$. Therefore $\sup(A)=1/2$.

I'm expecting the supremum of $B$ as $1$ but not sure how to conclude that.

Comment: Usually $n$ is used for natural numbers and $x$ is used for reals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your term in the form $$\frac{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this set is defined on the natural numbers.  You might rewrite the expression as
$$
f(n)=\dfrac{n+2}{n^2+1}=\dfrac{1/n+2/n^2}{1+1/n^2}
$$ 
Then it's easy to see than the infimum of this set of numbers is $0$.
The supremum of the set is $3/2$, which occurs when $n=1$, since the expression is decreasing in $n$. If you real think that $n \in \mathbb{R}$, then just take the derivative of $f(n)$, set it equal to zero, and evaluate $f(n)$ at those two points.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $n \in \mathbb{N}$, observe the function $f(n) = \dfrac{n+2}{n^2+1}$ is a decreasing function ( you can check ), then $f(n) \le f(1) = \dfrac{3}{2}$ which is a maximum and is therefore a supremum as well. For the infimum, observe that $f(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$,and together with the decreasing property of $f$ we conclude the infimum is $0$.